# Extend/Override Javascript Included from Layout (head->link)

Tags: layout, javascript, overrides, extend

I want to extend: 
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/edit-tree.js

Which is loaded by layout:
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_category_edit.xml:12

[image]

Why I want to expand this javascript? To put a password input.

[image]

I tried to override using requirejs-config.js, but doesn't work.

[image]

What should I do? What methods are there to put an input on this confirm modal?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

I have overwritten layout:
app/code/Vendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_category_edit.xml

[image]

And I added app/code/Vendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/edit-tree.js.